# Using if condition to display in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to display `manager_id` using the `user_id` and `role_id` as inputs in MySQL. This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT cbm_user.user_id as user_id
IF (cbm_roles.role_id = 3 THEN SELECT cbm_user.manager_id as manager_id, cbm_user.user_id as user_id, cbm_user_role.role_id as role_id from cbm_user left outer join cbm_user_role on cbm_user.user_id = cbm_user_role.user_id, left outer join cbm_roles on cbm_user_role.role_id = cbm_roles.role_id where role_id = 3)
END if;
```

But I get

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (cbm_roles.role_id = 3 THEN SELECT cbm_user.manager_id as manager_id, cbm_use' at line 2

error. What should I do? I also want to add two more conditions. How can I do that?

Comment: your if condition is format is wrong, refer docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: *SELECT cbm_user.user_id as user_id* and a comma is needed before the next item to select is listed :)

Comment: (1) missing a comma where the error points, (2) A `SELECT` subquery needs parentheses around it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using IF in wrong way.
2. You are using join in wrong way means "," join as well left join together.

You can use your query below 2 types-

**USE OF IF**

```
SELECT cbm_user.user_id AS user_id
IF (cbm_roles.role_id = 3,cbm_user.manager_id,NULL) AS manager_id, 
cbm_user.user_id AS user_id, cbm_user_role.role_id AS role_id 
FROM cbm_user 
LEFT JOIN cbm_user_role ON cbm_user.user_id = cbm_user_role.user_id 
LEFT JOIN cbm_roles ON cbm_user_role.role_id = cbm_roles.role_id 
WHERE role_id = 3;
```

**use of case**

```
SELECT cbm_user.user_id AS user_id
CASE WHEN cbm_roles.role_id = 3 THEN cbm_user.manager_id END AS manager_id, 
cbm_user.user_id AS user_id, cbm_user_role.role_id AS role_id 
FROM cbm_user 
LEFT JOIN cbm_user_role ON cbm_user.user_id = cbm_user_role.user_id 
LEFT JOIN cbm_roles ON cbm_user_role.role_id = cbm_roles.role_id 
WHERE role_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your statement:

- missing comma between fields
- incorrect use of if() function
- extra comma in join expression

To sum up: you cannot use an if() function to decide what tables to join. I fixed the syntax errors below, but I do not think that this is the query you want.

```
SELECT cbm_user.user_id as user_id,
       IF(cbm_roles.role_id = 3, cbm_user.manager_id, null) as manager_id,
       cbm_user_role.role_id as role_id
from cbm_user
left outer join cbm_user_role on cbm_user.user_id = cbm_user_role.user_id
left outer join cbm_roles on cbm_user_role.role_id = cbm_roles.role_id
where cbm_user_role.role_id = 3
```